# How to create a collapsing toolbar with a ViewPager inside?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-viewpager, toolbar

I have a `ScrollView` with a `ViewPager` (for the images) and a `LinearLayout` for the dot indicators. I also want a collapsible toolbar with the `ViewPager` and the `LinearLayout` inside it. I have added the my code as well as a code for the collapsible toolbar. But I don't know how to implement the `ViewPager` and the `LinearLayout` inside that. Please somebody give me the correct working code?

**my code**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/aboutslscrollview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/viewPager"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />


    </RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="About"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**code found for the collapsible toolbar**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/expandedImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/beach_scene"

            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
         app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" >


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sample_string"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Can you please tell me where to add the `ViewPager` and dotindicator(`LinearLayout`) inside the collapsible toolbar?

Answer (score -1):

The container layout-RelativeLayout of the ViewPager and LinearLayout should be inside CollapsingToolbarLayout. And set the property like this to make it collapsible with scroll events.

```
app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
```

Solution:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout                 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.birjuvachhani.myapplication.ScrollingActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:titleEnabled="false"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="250dp" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/viewPager"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

        <!-- Main content goes here. -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Please stop just dumping the same code into multiple answers. If the same exact code is an answer to both, then one of them is a duplicate. And answers should include explanation of *why* it is the solution so that the poster learns something and so can future readers here.

Comment: Hello Birju.Your code works fine except there is a default toolbar created by the mainActivity.I was able to hide that toolbar but in the new toolbar(which was created in the coorddinaatorLayout) is blank and the ones which was there in the original toolbar(the three lines to open navigation drawer, fragment name and 3 dots at right for settings ) are not there.I want to know how to add those to the new toolbar

Comment: to add options menu(3 dots), you have to create a menu file under res>menu and override these methods in MainActivity: 1. onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 2. onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)